# TLS session resumption failure Windows 2012 R2

Tags: ssl, openssl, windows

I have an issue with TLS session resumption failing on a specific Windows 2012 R2 client connecting to an apache server running openSSL.

When I make the initial request the server provides a session ticket. If I make another request within 5 minutes (timeout for TLS session ticket) the abbreviated handshake fails and on the client side I get a fatal alert `49` (`TLS1_ALERT_ACCESS_DENIED/SEC_E_LOGON_DENIED`). TLS resumption works fine in other 2012 R2 environments.

I am having trouble determining if this problem is on the client or server side. Server is `Apache/2.2.22` with `OpenSSL/1.0.1e-fips`.

[Client Network Capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9PgML.png)

[Server Logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7LE3R.png)